# JavaScript Validation For TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want validation for textbox and textbox is list type so how to validate using JavaScript?

I need the following validation:

Textbox should not be empty, no duplication

Given below is my code

```html
@model List
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCategory", "CategoryAndSubCategory", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "category" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  @Html.Label("Category Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
  @Html.EditorFor(a => a[j].Category, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Category Name", @style = "text-transform: capitalize" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a[j].Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

Comment: Please do not capitalise every word. It is extremely annoying to read

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks sir, I keep it in my mind.

Comment: What is your model. And what is `[j]` (that is not even declared and I assume you really have a `for` loop somewhere). Your code wont even compile! And what are you really trying to do here - create multiple Categories but ensure no duplicated?